# Split with empty line delimiter

Tags: python

I'm having trouble splitting a text file using empty line `"\n\n"` delimiters.

```
re.split("\n", aString)
```

works but

```
re.split("\n\n", aString)
```

just returns the whole string.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give an example of the file you are using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beware the [line ending conventions of different operating systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)!

- Windows: CRLF (`\r\n`)
- Linux and other Unices: LF (`\n`)
- Old Mac: CR (`\r`)

You are probably failing because the double newline you are looking for is in a Windows-encoded text file, and will appear as `\r\n\r\n`, not `\n\n`.

The `repr()` function will tell you for sure what your line endings are:

```
>>> mystring = #[[a line of your file]]
>>> repr(mystring)
"'\\nmulti\\nline\\nstring '"
```

---

Are you sure that you don't just want to read the file line by line in the first place?

```
with open(file.txt, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print (line)
```

Comment: He will get his alleged problem on Windows only if the file is open in binary mode. Opening binary files in text mode is a common pronlem. Opening text files in binary mode is rare.

Comment: This solved it, thanks!  I did originally create the file using windows, so that explains it.  I'm parsing a text file I created with data separated by lines and empty lines (for readability when inputting it).  I'll try "with open..." but I'll have to add something to parse the empty lines still (the data is '2d')

Comment: If you're reading a file line by line (with the `for line in file:` pattern), then empty lines will show up as `""` or possibly `"\r\n"`. You can just do a check for that.

Comment: So simply ask if it is an empty line: